# Derivative of $y =\sin^{-1}(\frac{a}{x})$ w.r.t. x

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am unsure of this derivative. The answer should apparently be $\frac{-a}{x\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$ by using the chain rule. However I arrived at a slightly different answer using implicit diff of $\frac{-a}{x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}}$. I arrived at this answer by noticing $\cos(\sin^{-1}(\frac{a}{x})) = \sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{x^2}}$ by forming a right angled triangle with hypotenuses of 1.

The two derivatives agree on positive values for x, but they have opposite signs for negative values of x (surely mine is correct since at negative values of x the gradient should be negative not positive)?

Comment: Your answer is correct, not the answer given. The reason is because $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, so the given answer should have been $$\frac{-a}{|x|\sqrt{x^2-a^2}}$$

Comment: $\sin(a/x)$ has no inverse, unless you restrict the domain. Which is your domain?

Comment: @leonbloy $\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)$ is the inverse of $a\sin x$, not $\sin\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. The given answer is only valid for $x>0$ in the denominator and it should have been $|x|=\sqrt{x^{2}}$ instead of x as mentioned by @Ninad Munshi.

Alternatively applying the differentiation rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arcsin(u(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^{2}(x)}}u'(x)$$ and the chain rule we obtain that $$\frac{d}{dx}arcsin(\frac{a}{x})=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{a}{x})}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{a}{x})^{2}}}=-\frac{a}{x^{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{a^{2}}{x^{2}}}}.$$